# KOMODO, what is a project and why it cannot be created

Tags: project-management, komodo

I wonder, what is a project (what it consists of and what is its purpose) in KOMODO[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2ZSA.jpg)

and why, when I attempt to create one, KOMODO cycles like in the picture attached.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not asking this on the Komodo forums?

Comment: @harrymc No. Can you point me to that forum ?

Comment: https://community.komodoide.com/